# How to create a JSON object from a BSON string which contains ISODate

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, bson

I am trying to create a JSON object from a string which contains ISODate.

```
var teststring = '{ "_id" : "test001", "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2013-04-02T10:37:21.529Z") }';
console.log(JSON.parse(teststring));
```

Getting the ERROR:

```
undefined:1
{ "_id" : "test001", "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2013-04-02T10:37:21.529Z") }
                                     ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand upon the answer by @user1896296

```
var valid = teststring.replace("ISODate(", "").replace(")", "");
```

is not very robust and shouldn't be used for production worthy code. Use a regular expression to do your replacement.

```
var isoRegex = /ISODate\((".+?")\)/g;
teststring = teststring.replace(isoRegex, function (match, parenGroup) {
    return parenGroup;
});
var parsedObj = JSON.parse(teststring);
```

This will work correctly even in this situation:

```
{
    "_id" : "test001",
    "RandomUserInput" : "Sometimes I like to say ISODate(\"2013-04-02T10:37:21.529Z\") in the body of my replies!",
    "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2013-04-02T10:37:21.529Z")
}
```

Since any double quotes inside the user's input must be escaped, the regular expression can't possibly match on user-supplied input.

Furthermore, if you actually want to parse those fields into date objects, you could write a helper function like so:

```
var isoRegex = /"([^"]+?)"\s*:\s*ISODate\((".+?")\)/g;
function parseBson (bson) {
    var dateProps = [];
    bson = bson.replace(isoRegex, function (match, propName, dateStr) {
        dateProps.push(propName);
        return '"' + propName + '" : ' + dateStr;
    });

    var obj = JSON.parse(bson);

    for (var i in dateProps)
        obj[dateProps[i]] = new Date(obj[dateProps[i]]);

    return obj;
}

var parsedObj = parseBson(teststring);
```

Note, this function would only work for top-level attributes. Trying to automatically convert nested properties would get tricky.

Comment: This answer misses the point of the question, which is how to parse mongo's extended json format.  One off regexes are definitely not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your teststring is not a valid JSON string, since

```
ISODate("2013-04-02T10:37:21.529Z")
```

is not a valid JSON Datetype (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example)).

So you have to transform your textstring into valid JSON before JSON.parse() can parse it.

For your case a simple/naive text-replacement could solve the problem:

```
//this should work:
var valid = teststring.replace("ISODate(", "").replace(")", "");
var parsedObj = JSON.parse(valid);
```

Keep in mind that `replace()` will replace the first occurrence (or all occurrences, when you use regexp).

Answer (score 0):

In C#/.Net you can use Regex.Replace:

```
    var isoRegex = new Regex("ISODate[(](.+?)[)]");
    json = isoRegex.Replace(json, "$1");
```

This will change `ISODate("2013-04-02T10:37:21.529Z")` to `"2013-04-02T10:37:21.529Z"`.